# Resetting NetSuite Sandbox to Default Without Production Data

Tags: javascript, netsuite, sandbox

I'm seeking advice on resetting a NetSuite sandbox to its original, default state (no data, default settings) after it's been refreshed from the production account. The aim is to use the sandbox for testing without production data interference.

Challenges:
Existing methods mainly suggest refreshing from production, which is not suitable for our needs.
Manual data cleanup is overly time-consuming and may miss hidden configurations.

Questions:
Is a full reset to a "newly provisioned" state possible for a NetSuite sandbox?
Are there recommended practices or tools for thoroughly cleaning the sandbox environment?

Any guidance or insights on achieving a clean slate for development and testing in a NetSuite sandbox would be greatly appreciated.